# База данных библиотеки

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Я делаю приложение для базы данных библиотеки. Реализовал добавление, изменение и удаление объектов. Но в случае, если объект с внешним ключом, мне приходится вводить него, хотя техническая информация должна быть сокрыта для пользователя. Можно вместо него выводить какое-то еще одно поле, но тогда уникальность отпадает. Не знаю, что делать. Приложил диаграмму всех классов.
MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Library
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string connectionString;
        private DataTable dataTable;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-P14D9V4Q;Initial Catalog=Library; Integrated Security=True";
            LibraryGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += LibraryGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn;
        }

        private void LibraryView(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedTable = ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(); // Получаем имя выбранной таблицы
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + selectedTable;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                    dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    LibraryGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void AddObject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    // Set the SelectCommand property for dataAdapter
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content, connection);

                    dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter).GetUpdateCommand();
                    try
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        string messageBoxText = "Неправильно введено Id";
                        string caption = "Ошибка ввода"+Tables.SelectedItem.ToString();
                        MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OKCancel;
                        MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Warning;
                        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon);
                    }
                  

                    RefreshData();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void UpdateObject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView selectedRow = LibraryGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

            if (selectedRow != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        // Set the SelectCommand property for dataAdapter
                        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content, connection);

                        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter).GetUpdateCommand();
                        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);

                        RefreshData();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void DeleteObject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView selectedRow = LibraryGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

            if (selectedRow != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();

                        selectedRow.Row.Delete();

                        // Set the SelectCommand property for dataAdapter
                        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content, connection);

                        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter).GetUpdateCommand();
                        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);

                        RefreshData();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void RefreshData()
        {
            string selectedTable = ((ComboBoxItem)Tables.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + selectedTable;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                    dataTable.Clear();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    LibraryGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void LibraryGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            // Исключение Id
            if (e.PropertyName.EndsWith("Id"))
                e.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Library.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Library"
        xmlns:SqlServer="clr-namespace:System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;assembly=EntityFramework.SqlServer"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="500" Width="800" ShowInTaskbar="False" Title="Библиотека" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox x:Name="Tables" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" SelectionChanged="LibraryView" 
                  Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Libs"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Librarians"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Groups"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Faculties"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Students"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="S_Cards"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Teachers"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="T_Cards"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Departments"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Books"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Authors"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Categories"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Presses"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Themes"/>
        </ComboBox>

        <DataGrid x:Name="LibraryGrid" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10">
            <Button x:Name="AddButton" Content="Добавить" Click="AddObject" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="UpdateButton" Content="Изменить" Click="UpdateObject" Margin="5"/>
            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Content="Удалить" Click="DeleteObject" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: img]

Comment: *Но в случае, если объект с внешним ключом, мне приходится вводить него, хотя техническая информация должна быть сокрыта для пользователя.* - переведите эту фразу на русский язык...

Comment: Аналогичная пользователю выше просьба

Comment: а почему она должна быть скрыта? у каждого объекта (автор, книга ...) есть уникальный номер и по факту это просто "техническая информация". Если вам не нравится использовать Id замените его или просто добавьте вторичный уникальный ключ, который не будет выглядеть как "техническая информация"

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что это логично. Но препод почему-то так не думает, вот и решил здесь спросить. Спасибо за пояснения

Answer (score 0):

Буду не очень оригинален, но всё таки спрошу: Вы в курсе что такое венгерская нотация? Рекомендую Вам использовать именование полей как <сокращение имени таблицы>_<имя_поля>. Например: имя таблицы Librarian, поле Id - libr_id, тогда схема читается не в пример легче. (не подумайте что умничаю - просто опыт, но дело Ваше в любом случае. Тогда не придётся в связанных таблицах видеть множество полей id и гадать что откуда)

Что касается вопроса - если я правильно понял - то вопрос состоит в том, как задавать id родительской таблицы при добавлении потомков. То есть если у Вас есть перечень авторов - и Вы хотите добавить книгу, как указать id автора в запись о книге. В этом случае - самый простой способ - это передавать id атора непосредственно в окно редактирования параметров книги или выводить всех (или не очень) авторов в выпадающий список в окне редактирования книги и брать id автора при сохранении уже из источника данных этого выпадающего списка.